# tell wicket:link not to overwrite markup

Tags: inheritance, hyperlink, wicket, markup

I'm working on some SVG-Buttons for a User Interface. I have to dynamically create a Link in the java files with some code in it from the markup. The following code is an example of my markup-input.

html-markup input:

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <wicket:link wicket:id="test">
            <path ..../>
            <path ..../>
        </wicket:link>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I want the markup-output to look like this:

html-markup output:

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <a wicket:id="test" xlink:href="someurl">
            <path ..../>
            <path ..../>
        </a>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The thing is, that wicket will end up deleting the path-instructions in the markup html which it isn't supposed to do so. Is there any way to do this properly?
For testing I came up with some dirty work around I'm not satisfied with because it hurts the wicket convention of not creating html in java. It looks like the following:

html-markup dirty way input:

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <wicket:container wicket:id="linkbeginning">
            <path ..../>
            <path ..../>
        <wicket:container wicket:id="linkending">
    </g>
</svg>
```

java dirty-way:

```
add(new Label("linkbeginning", "<a xlink:href =\""+linkurl+"\">");
add(new Label("linkending", "</a>");
```

which ended in this output:

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <a xlink:href="someurl">
            <path ..../>
            <path ..../>
        </a>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a regular Link component with an anchor tag? Ex:

```
<a wicket:id="link">
    <div>link</div>
    <span>span</span>
</a>
```

and code

```
add(new Link("link")
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick()
        {

        }
    });
```

Link component will keep its internal markup body.